Use Axios with NextJS 15 Server Action Function
TL;DR: Using Axios with my NextJS 15 application to upload a file and have it display the upload progress. Issue is has a possible solution.

I was looking into using Axios with my NextJS 15 application to upload a file and have it display the upload progress. This would also include multi-file uploading and I would also love to figure out uploading large file. What my issue is now, figuring out if I could call a service action function within axios and call the await uploadFileToS3(file, S3Payload) function within my upload page ?!
Such as:
// app/actions/s3File.ts

"use server"

import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache"

type S3Payload = {
  uploadDestination: string
  bucket: string
  hostName: string
  uploadEndpoint: string
}

export async function uploadFileToS3( formData: FormData, payload: S3Payload ): Promise<any[]> {
  const s3 = new S3Client({
    ...
  })
  
  const { uploadDestination, bucket, hostName, uploadEndpoint } = payload

  try {
    const files = formData.getAll("file") as File[]
    
    const response = await Promise.all(
      files.map(async (file) => {
        const {name: fileName, type: fileType, lastModified: date, size: fileSize} = file
        const fileExtension = fileType.split("/")\[1\]
        const fileID = `${uploadDestination}\_CUSTOMRANDOMID` as string
        const filePath = `${uploadDestination}/${fileID}.${fileExtension}`
        
        const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer()
        const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer)
        
        const uploadFileObject = {
          Bucket: bucket,
          Key: filePath,
          Body: buffer,
          ContentType: fileType,
          ContentLength: fileSize,
        }
        
        const uploadFile = new PutObjectCommand(uploadFileObject)
        const upload = await s3.send(uploadFile)
      })
    )
    
    revalidatePath("/")
    return response
  } catch (error) {
    ...
  }
}

and my upload file is currently looking like this:
// uploadPage/component.tsx

...

import { Dropzone, DropzoneProps, IMAGE_MIME_TYPE } from '@mantine/dropzone';
import { uploadFileToS3 } from "@/app/actions/s3File";

...

async function handleOnSubmit(e: any) {
  setUploading(true)
 
  const files = e
  const uploadDestination = mediaType
  
  try {
    const formData = new FormData()
    
    files.forEach((file) => formData.append("file", file))
    // This is where I think the Axios would come in effect for upload progress?!
    await uploadFileToS3(formData, {
      uploadDestination, // Picture | Video | Audio | ECT
      bucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_S3_BUCKET_NAME!,
      hostName: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_S3_HOST_NAME!,
      uploadEndpoint: `https://${process.env.NEXT\_PUBLIC\_S3\_BUCKET\_NAME!}.${process.env.NEXT\_PUBLIC\_S3\_HOST\_NAME!}`
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("File(s) couldn't be uploaded to S3", error)
  }
}

return <>
  ...

  <Dropzone
    onDrop={(files) => handleOnSubmit(files)}
    onReject={(files) => console.log('rejected files', files)}
    loading={isUploading}
    bg="none"
    radius="md"
    c="white"
    {...props}
  >
    <Group justify="center" gap="2rem" style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }} py="4rem">
      <Dropzone.Accept>
        <FileUploadIcon variant="twotone" />
      </Dropzone.Accept>
      
      <Dropzone.Reject> 
        <Cancel01Icon variant="twotone" />
      </Dropzone.Reject>
      
      <Dropzone.Idle>
        <CloudUploadIcon variant="twotone" size="5rem" />
      </Dropzone.Idle>
      
      <Stack gap="0" m="0" p="0">  
        <Title c="white" lh="1" fw="900" ff="text" ta={{base: "center", lg: "left"}}>
          {uploadTitle ? uploadTitle : "Upload Media"}
        </Title>
        <Text size="sm" c="grey" lh="1" ta={{base: "center", lg: "left"}}>
      {helperText ? helperText : "Drag and Drop or Click to Upload File(s)."}
        </Text>
       </Stack>
    </Group>  
  </Dropzone>
  <Progress radius="0 0 0 1rem" size="xl" value={uploadProgress} color="primary" mt="0.5rem" animated /> 
  ...
</>

I have also tried to add this to the async function handleOnSubmit(e: any) function
files.forEach((file: string | Blob) => {
  formData.append("file", file)
  axios
    .post(
      uploadFileToS3(
        formData,
        s3Payload
      ),
      {
        headers: {
          'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
        },
        maxContentLength: 2e10,
        maxBodyLength: 2e10,
        onUploadProgress: (event: any) => {
           console.log("Hello from event", event)
           setUploadProgress(Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100))
        }
      }
    ).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.response) {
        console.log(error.response)
        console.log("server responded")
      } else if (error.request) {
        console.log("network error")
      } else {
        console.log(error)
      }
    })
})

This will upload the content through the Server Action but won't run the rest of the operation such as onUploadProgress or the completed .then. It returns the response error of POST https://DEVSERVER/PAGE/[object%20Promise] 404 (Not Found).

I have figured a possible solution? However, I'm unsure if it makes sense to do so or just seems redundant?
But I have created an API route to effectively collect the data; then send it to a controller to separate the formData and create different variables for the files and the payload; then I pass that controller data down to the server action.
This does seem to be working.
The API route looks something like this:
// api/upload/route.ts

import { handleFileUpload } from "@/app/controllers/upload.controller";

export async function POST(req: any) {
    return handleFileUpload(req)
}

The controller looks something like this:
// controllers/upload.controller.ts

import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { uploadFileToS3 } from "@/app/actions/s3File.ts";

export const handleFileUpload = async (req: any) => {
  try {
    const form = await req.formData()
    const files = form.getAll("files") as any

    const payloadRAW = form.get("payload")
    const {
      uploadDestination,
      mediaID,
      bucket,
      uploadEndpoint,
      pathname,
      redirectPath
    } =  JSON.parse(payloadRAW)

    const payload = {
      uploadDestination,
      mediaID,
      bucket,
      uploadEndpoint,
      pathname,
      redirectPath
    } as any

    const uploadURL = await uploadFileToS3(files, payload);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "success", uploadURL });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading file:", error);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "failure", reason: error.message });
  }
}

I then reconfigured my server action to take in the Files: File[] instead of the formData: FormData, along with some other general changes.
